# Keep part of mesh square when applying subdivision surface

Tags: modeling

I am applying a subsurface modifier to the body of my plane, I need to model the nose in such a way that it stays as sharp and square as possible. I don't see any vertex group option like in the displacement modifier, so I don't know how to achieve this.

Can this be done or should I separate the nose in to another piece without subsurf?

Non subsurf version

[image: Non subsurf version]

Subsurf version, I tried with mean crease 1.0 but still got rounded corners.

[image]

Comment: Try using crease on the edges which are the corner of the mesh. It should have more effect than using creases on edges in a relatively flat area (as in your screenshot).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still coming out a bit too doughy.

Comment: Does tweaking the topology/[adding supporting geometry](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface?rq=1) help?

Comment: @gandalf3 - I think you left a comment about separating the mesh, I had a notification but its been deleted, how can this be done please?

Comment: That's odd.. I don't remember leaving or deleting a comment..? Anyway, you can separate the selection with `Y` and separate the selection into a new object with `P`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsurf is very dependent on how your topology flows. When you see an ugly pole that pinches your geometry that's when you got to rethink the topology. Poles are not evil but they are unavoidable as they control the flow of your topology but must be used sparingly, specially in organic or semi-organic surfaces. The pole in your geometry doesn't look right:

[image: Imgur]

I would suggest changing the topology so you get better subdivision. The red lines control the flow and the blue lines reinforce the geometry to crease the edges:

[image: Imgur]

Make sure to clean up triangles; you want all quads when possible.