# Create sharp crease in smooth Mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

While modeling an Audi R8 I have the following problem. The thing I want to create is seen in this image:

[image: Audi R8 reference image]

I want to create a sharp crease (outlined in red) which starts around the first exhaust and then goes to the second. 
Is there an efficient way to do this (I also use the Subdivision Surface Modifier for this model).

Comment: I think this is more a duplicate of [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6425/599)

Comment: @gandalf3 I knew the thing with changing the Mean Crease but I thought there would be another way. But now I tried it with a Loop Cut and it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to specify what the subsurf modifier should smooth and how much, you can use the [Mean crease](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html#weighted-edge-creases) setting. This will allow you to (basically) tell the subsurf that it can subdivide an edge, but leave it sharp (instead of smoothing it). There are other techniques for getting sharp edges in an organic model workflow, most of which are discussed [here](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/16/using-sharp-edges-in-blender/).

- It discusses using more edge loops very close together, which is effective, but very inefficient.
- It discusses using weighted creases (which is what I recommended above)
- And it discusses the edge-split modifier

...all of which are effective tools for making sharp edges. Each has its benefits and draw-backs.