# How to get rid of subsurf overhangs?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, bevel

Here is the shape I want to achieve, sharp square hole in the cylinder:
[image]

I did inset, extrude and beveled edges to keep square form.

The problem is when I am applying subsurf modifier, it distorts hole edges with weird overhangs:
[image]

Here is my blender file:

[image]

And here is modifier settings:
[image]

Comment: related:  [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges) and [Create sharp crease in smooth Mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6924/create-sharp-crease-in-smooth-mesh)

Comment: Using sharp edges will tear surface inside hole and beveling ends up with this ovehangs. I can achieve very sharp shape with creases but I want edges to look beveled

Comment: watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBkwodrQq_4

Comment: can you show modifiers settings, or share the file (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com - free, permanent, integrated, then edit your question and paste the provided link), I tried to replicate but with a subsurf 3 I get different results (better) I guess edge split or something else in the geometry  is involved here...

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add more information.

Comment: @m.ardito I uploaded my file and added screenshot with modifiers settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by others, those corner triangles (probably bevel applied) are involved in this (edge split is not),

[image]

I tred adding some more loopcut, eg. like

[image]

with subsurf:

[image]

in object mode:

[image]

compared to your squared hole:

[image]

under another angle

[image]

here is visible the full cylinder, without subsurf

[image]

with subsurf (note that I also removed sharp edges but added loops at top and bottom)

[image]

and in object mode (here I disabled edge split: top/bottom loops gives the edge more definition even with the subsurf)

[image]

here a test file

[image]

Comment: I wish there was a way to do this without cutting through all the cylinder. However this method gives exactly what I want to get.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is cause by the beveling of the edges that you did. When you applied the bevel operation, a small triangle was created in each corner.

[image]

Triangles are notorious for having issues like this when being subdivided. In this case, it may be difficult (although not impossible) to remove the triangle completely though. If you restructure the mesh so that the triangle is located on a section that isn't a corner the smoothing will look much nicer. Here is a way you could do that.

[image]

Here is a comparison between the corners when subdivided:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've also came to this solution earlier, but it still produces artifacts with thinner inset outline.