# How to achieve the round corners of a black piano key?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to model a black piano key using Blender but I'm facing some difficulties when trying to recreate the rounded upper front edges of the black key.

[image: Picture of a black piano key]

The closest I have come to achieving this is by first beveling the two front upper vertices in the corners using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> command. Then beveling all edges except the edges of the rounded corners. However, as you can see, the subdivided result is far from perfect!

[image: Start] [image: Beveled vertices] [image: Beveled edges] [image: Subdivided]

Maybe I should try a completely different approach? What do you Blender experts make of this?

Thanks in advance for any kind of input!

Comment: I think you can find what you need in the answers to this question: [How can I make some edges on my model sharper and others more rounded?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/how-can-i-make-some-edges-on-my-model-sharper-and-others-more-rounded) If not, let me know and I can help you some more. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, that post seems to contain a lot of helpful information. I'll read it carefully and let you know if it helped me. Again, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm used for subdivision surfaces works best with quads. You have many n-gons in your mesh, which will lead to artifacts.
[image]

You should at least convert the front and top face to quads. You can do that in two steps: select the top and front face and press [Ctrl+T] to triangulate them.
[image]
[image]

Now select two triangles that you want to merge to a quad and press [Alt+J]. Repeat until you have no more triangles.
[image]
[image]

To keep the edges sharper, add a bevel modifier on top of the subsurf. Now you can control the roundness / sharpness through the bevel's "Width" parameter.
[image]

The result should look like this:
[image]

Comment: I had no idea about this... It sure does look much cleaner, and I'm able to get these round corners. Thanks! However, in order to have the corners round, like in the picture, I have to set a pretty high width in the Bevel modifier. The problem is, all other edges needs to be sharper, and I have no idea how to achieve that. Using the bevel command, instead of the modifier, on certain edges doesn't give me the same result. Maybe I should explain further, and maybe some pictures, in a new post?

Comment: To get a perfect result you will probably have to apply the bevel modifier at some point and tweak the vertices by hand. You can also combine it with the technique @Thom Blair III mentioned in his comment to your question: changing the Edge Crease. If that doesn't help either, additional loopcuts near the edges will give them a sharper appearance as well. And in my oppinion a realistic material will influence the appearance of a model much more than the actual shape ;)