# Forced normals and hard edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, normals

I'm trying to learn blender in a perspective of making meshes that I can export to game engines. Making nice looking high polys seems to go okey for me, but I have a hard time with controlling my normals when doing my low poly mesh.

Here I have a low poly model with some bevels on it. What I want to do (because of the bevel) is to force the normals marked red to be flat. I've successfully done so using the blend4web plugin. I also want to keep a sharp edge around the faces on the inside (marked green), now there's where things get tricky for me.
I have been searching around and the only way I found that works is to split the edges. Now I really don't want to do that since this is a problem that appears quite often and I want to keep my low polys as intact as I can.

[image: mesh in edit mode, with edges marked]

[image: object mode showing the smooth edges]

I made an example in maya just to show you what I want. (This mesh is using the exact same topology and is all intact).

[image: example in maya]

Comment: related:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: You can use for your needs Blend4Web addon for Blender, there you can find very good Normal Editor that allow you to do what you want. You can read more about it here in the article https://www.blend4web.com/en/article/131/ . Addon is free and you can find it on blend4web.com in download section.

Answer (score 0):

Crease the edges you want to stay sharp. A value of 1 will be perfectly sharp. If you have any smoothing or subdivision surface modifier applied, as you reduce the value the edge shading will become increasingly smoothed. So if you want just a bit of smooth shading on certain edges you might try a value of .9 or something.

This is where the 'Crease' value adjustment is located.

[image]