# Black shadows on Faces, not a normals thing

Tags: modeling, rendering, light

this is the first time I've used this website, sorry if I dont organize the post wrong. I've been using Blender for a couple months now, so I'm not too terribly new, however, There are these weird black shadows on my model and its driving me crazy, as I cant get rid of them. They're not a normals issue, as I've already recalculated them and it's not that. Does anyone know what causes this? Its in object mode, by the way. It happens anywhere.
[image]
Its probably a problem with the way I modeled it or something, as it's happening around these sharp edges. Here is it in edit mode.
[image]
Here is it in edit mode. Does anyone see anything wrong that I did? I'm sure I did something wrong. 
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: That is caused by the smoothing. Add a subdivision modifier or a bevel modifier.

Comment: Oddly enough this actually *is* a normals thing.. The normals are interpolated at the sharp corners, almost as if the surface was rounded. This causes the dark colors mapped to the sides of the model to bleed around and appear on the front. Try adding more geometry (e.g. [supporting loopcuts](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6426/599))

Answer (score 4):

This occurs because you have smooth shading applied to your model. To resolve this, ensure affected topologies are selected, go to the Tool Panel <kbd>T</kbd> goto 'Shading' section select 'Flat'.

You can also apply an 'Edge Split' modifier, found under the Modifier tab in Properties Panel. Split edges need to be marked, once selected, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. Dragging the mouse up/down to define amount.

You may also add more Geometry to the mesh. Either manually with 'Edge Loops' <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or by adding a 'Subdivision Surface' modifier, also found in the Modifier tab in Properties Panel.