# Modeling a pointy mesh

Tags: modeling

I want to model a pointy mesh but I don't know what the right method is, because I have tried multiple of them and they doesn't seem right.

I tried to do it by linking every vertex to a single vertex at the tip.
The problem with that is that I won't be able to use a loop cut to sharpen the edges if I want to use a subsurf modifier after that, since I believe it doesn't work with triangles.
[image: 1]

Then, I tried to do it with four vertex linked in a same position and individually linked to the four others vertex of the mesh.
I'm wondering if this is a clean way to do it because those four vertex are not really necessary, if it is to place the loop cut.

The problem with that tho is that when I work with a mirror modifier on the X and Y axis, there will always be a hole in the middle (invisible when shrinked) since I can only link three vertex. Is that a problem ?
[image: 2]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

### Sharpen with Crease edges values

If is suitable with your geometry, you can use a high value of **Crease Edge** amount to the edges that start from the vertex you want pointy.

Pick the vertices, extend selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to set the Crease to <kbd>1</kbd>

[image]

More purple the edge is, higer the Crease value result.

---

If you are not interest on the sharp edges but only to create a spiky geometery, you can loopcut the piramid with a loopcut that lay in the plane that has the same normal of the base.

[image]

To opbtain this you can use the kinfe tool, or by extruding, or subdividing.

Double press <kbd>G</kbd> key to slide the loop near the vertex.

Comment: Related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6426/15140

Comment: Tnak you, is there a difference between sharpening an edge with a loop cut and a crease edge value after a subsurf modifier?

Comment: Creases don't add faces to your geometry, keep the model more clean, but with edgeloops you have more controle.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to add one vertex that is in the center of the mirror symmetry, and probably turn the clipping of the mirror on.
If you bevel the main edges of your mesh and add a subsurface modifier you will get this
[image]

with no hole in the center .... 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but don't understand what edges I need to bevel. (that's CTRL+B, right ?) [1]: http://i.imgur.com/GmpgQbJ.png