# How do I make a boxed extrusion on a cube that has a subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: modeling

When I try to extrude a face on a cube that has a subdivision surface modifier it's always circular. Even when using edge loops. How can I achieve this? I'm new so I'm sure I'm missing something here. There is still a lot of things I don't know how to do.

I would like to know how to get a box shaped extrusion (like the type of extrusion that you get on a cube with no subdivision surface on it) on a cube that has the subdivision surface modifier on it. The picture below shows what happens when I extrude on this cube that has the subdivision surface modifier on it. How can I make that circular extrusion rectangular?

Top picture is subdivision turned off and then you see in the bottom picture that when I turn it on my extrusion becomes circular.

[image: Here is subdivision surface switched off]

[image: Here is subdivision surface turned on]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your edgeloops? Maybe they are not enough or in the wrong position. See related questions: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface/6426#6426

Comment: I updated the original post. I'll check out those links. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the end face, and the four edges. Next press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to crease the selected edges.
You can also crease the edge loop at the base to make the extrusion like a cube. This method works mostly the same for extruding inwards as for extruding outwards. You may need to crease more edges, especially those on the face.

[image: Ill]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. What you showed here is what I do, but once I make an extrusion on one of those faces it is circular. I have updated my original post to show this. I want to be able to make the extrusion rectangular on a cube that has the subdivision surface modifier.

Comment: If you don't mind extra polygons, try beveling. Select a loopcut and press Ctrl+B

Comment: I'm confused as to how you are pulling on that circle extrusion and making it a square. This is what I'm talking about though

Comment: Use shift+e, and then move the cursor away

Comment: I'm trying this, but I can't do it successfully. What parts of the extrusion do you have selected when doing this?

Comment: I'm adding a .gif of what happens in my original post.

Comment: Cant add to the original post. Here is what happens when I try. http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2015081206z7QK7PcpITkIHmvO7CAy99&file=output_fygf9h.gif

Comment: You need to crease the edge on the front as well

Answer (score 1):

Make loopcuts along in the planes that are parallel to the circular face's normal and slide them.

[image][image][image]

Or crease all the edges around the border with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! While this does work, it messes up the symmetry of other extrusions I have. Is there any way to do it without loop cutting? I would like to be able to just do it to each extrusion separately if that is possible.

Comment: You can "loop cutting" and than "remove doubles" on the vertex of the mesh where you want to remove the loopcut effect. So it will affect only the wanted part. Or you can crease edges, did you try?

Comment: Here is a gif I just made. I'm selecting the faces and then using shift+e http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2015081206z7QK7PcpITkIHmvO7CAy99&file=output_fygf9h.gif

Comment: Extend your edge selection to at least all the edges shown in the last pic of the answer. Subdivision surface take in account not only one face, but also its neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

Select the end face, and the four edges. Next press Shift+E to crease the selected edges. You can also crease the edge loop at the base to make the extrusion like a cube. This method works mostly the same for extruding inwards as for extruding outwards. You may need to crease more edges, especially those on the face.

Thanks for the help everyone! This is an awesome community!

Comment: No problem, anytime :)