# subdivision surface sharp edges problem edge loops and creases don't work

Tags: modeling, mesh

how would i go about sub-surfing this and keeps its sharp edges?

[image]

more specifically i am having difficulty with subdividing the the plate like objects on its upper arms and thighs,i have tried the usual methods such as moving edge loops and adding creases but they all leave some kind unsightly deformity, especially when combined with the solidify modifier.

most of the other parts of this model such as its torso and head subdivide without issue.

just what am i doing wrong and how do i make its arm and leg plates smooth with deforming or losing definition?

[image]

this was marked as duplicate and linked to a question which told me to use supporting loops and creases which as i already stated doesn't work.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: Did you try a Bevel modifier with an `Angle` limiter?

Comment: i did try just now it didn't help, perhaps you could be specific about its use? it did seemingly nothing when i tried.