# How to make a cylinder cap concave?

Tags: modeling, objects

Probably really simple answer, but I can't seem to find any info about how to make a face concave.

Comment: Concave like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n3FbZ.png)?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way you can do this is with [*Proportional Editing*](http://blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html) (<kbd>O</kbd>):

[image]

#### Steps taken in the gif

1. Add a cylinder (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Mesh > Cylinder*)
2. Enter *Edit Mode* (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
3. Select the top and bottom faces (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>*> Face* to set the selection mode, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to select)
4. Inset (<kbd>I</kbd>)
5. Select just the top face and inset again (<kbd>I</kbd>)
6. Add loopcuts (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> to adjust number of cuts)
7. Select the middle ngon
8. Turn on *Proportional Editing* (<kbd>O</kbd>) and set the falloff type in the header
9. Move the face down on the Z axis (<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>. Use <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> to adjust the falloff)
10. Add a subsurf modifier (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, where <kbd>1</kbd> refers to the number of subdivisions in the modifier. Can be any digit from <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>5</kbd>)
11. [Add supporting loopcuts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6425/599) (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) to control the subsurf.

Comment: @gandalf3♦ hahaha! I feel like a clairvoyant right now. After posting my answer I knew that you come with a better solution and take back my 'accept' points. Premonition came true :).

Comment: @Gonzou o.O haha. I nearly didn't answer after I saw your creative solution, but I figured I'd write something anyway since, well, two answers are better than one :)

Answer (score 7):

Add a *Cylinder* with *NGon cap fill type*. Select the upper edge loop with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel it. Set the bevel ***Segments*** number as desired. Next select the edge loop as pictured below, snap the cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*), select the other edge loops towards the top and press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, -1. Add some loop cuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to sharpen the edges (if you wish to add a *Subsurf Modifier* in the next step).
[image]

Now add the ***Subsurf Modifier*** and set the desired subdivisions number.
[image]

Smooth the faces clicking on the ***Smooth*** button in the *Edit* panel of the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]