# How to model a bee's segmented abdomen

Tags: modeling, mesh

I modelled the back of a bee using subsurface modelling.

[image]

I want it to have 'bumps' like this:

[image]

I did the above by duplicating the object a lot of times and then made shapes to use as a cut for the boolean modifier.
While the result looks 'ok' to me. Making changes is a real pain.

I also tried using a latice but  that didn't turn out well either.

What would be a good technique to do this?

Here the file in case it helps to try on the actual model.
[image]

Comment: It would help if you could add some reference images of what you are going for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [edge creases](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface) to sharpen edges when using the subdivision surface modifier, and simple bevelling and scaling to generate this effect.

Start with a subdivided capsule with a topology like this:

[image]

Select an edge where you'd like to create a segment in the bee's abdomen:

[image]

Bevel the edge using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, then move the cursor slightly to create a small bevel.

[image]

Select the rear edge.

[image]

Scale it down.

[image]

Select the front edge, open the options panel with the shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>, then crank up the crease to around 0.75.

[image]

Finally, you can play with the scale and position of the edges of each segment, and repeat this process to create the segmented abdomen.

[image]

Comment: What do you use to make a gif like that?

Comment: I use the nice and free Screen to Gif: https://screentogif.codeplex.com