# How can I make a groove in a sphere?

Tags: modeling

How can I make grooves in a sphere. If I use the Subsurf modifier, the edges don't keep sharp. And if I use a crease of 1 I loose the smoothness of the sphere.

[image]

Here what I get using crease at 1.[image]

Here the illustration of the problem I encounter. Left is only 'Mark Sharp' applied, middle is only 'Edge Crease of 1', right is 'Mark Sharp' and 'Edge Crease' both applied.

[image]

Artefacts appear.

[image]

Comment: Could you describe better why creasing the edges is not satisfying solution?

Comment: Because artefacts appear. What is the best way to shape these grooves?

Comment: You could try micopoly displacement from a texture map.

Comment: Using Crease in this case assumes extruding area of interest and then creasing its edges. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: Post blend file?

Comment: Could anyone explain to me how to create a groove in a sphere? This can be usefull for other newbies...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a sharp 'crease' to a model by using the edge split modifier. I see in your screenshot that you already have the modifier applied.

The edge split modifier will treat sharp edges as qualified to split, regardless of the Edge Angle specified in the modifier. Edge Crease forces a pinching effect to be applied to the geometry generated from the subsurf modifier. By combining these two, you can get a sharp edge while maintaining the smoothing effect of the subsurf modifier.

In edit mode, select the edges you wish to effect and press 'Ctrl+E' to open the Edges menu. Select 'Mark Sharp'.This will split the edges to create sharp edges in the shading.
[image: Sphere with sharp edges]

Afterwards, select those same edges **and** the edges connecting the corners of your grooves. Use 'Ctrl+E' again to open the Edges menu and use the 'Edge Crease' option to pinch the geometry into a sharp profile, effectively ignoring the rounded edges from the subsurf modifier.
[image: Groove represented in a subsurfed sphere.]

Here is a sphere showcasing the different effects. Left is normal geometry, middle is 'Mark Sharp' Applied, and right is 'Mark Sharp' and 'Edge Crease' applied.

[image: Comparison between edges.]

Comment: Very usefull.... It allows a control of the edges with the Subsurf modifier. How to apply this to the model I'm trying to reproduce? I tried to extrude the edges marked as sharp but the vertical edges don't keep their sharpness.

Comment: I rewrote my answer to better reflect the issue you are trying to resolve.

Comment: What is the use of  selecting 'Mark Sharp'.before applying the Edge Crease? Maybe I'm doing something wrong but applying an edge crease in the corner raise the intersection of the edges creating a point.

Comment: You can apply the 'Mark Sharp' and 'Edge Crease' in any order. Mark Sharp splits the edges to provide the sharp look. Edge Crease allows you to pinch the subsurf geometry to follow the sharp edges instead of smoothing them out. Keep in mind that unlike Mark Sharp, Edge Crease takes a number value to set how intense the crease is. After selecting Edge Crease, and before you click to confirm the crease, you can drag your mouse to increase or decrease the effect, Or you can press the number one and click to apply the maximum crease.

Comment: I updated the post. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but as you can see there is no difference between the 'Mark Sharp' worflow and the 'Mark Sharp' and 'Edge Crease' both applied. Thus some artefacts appear on the intersections between edges.

Comment: I cannot see the update to the post. Perhaps you can upload a new screenshot to imgur.com and share the link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48907/discussion-between-thomas-pendergrass-and-grobby).