# Multiresolution Mesh Deform

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I'm trying to paint a scales texture onto a cube using sculpt mode but the only way i know is to use the multiresolution modifier and that makes my cube turn into a sphere is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Comment: There are 2 ways - subdividing with *Simple* method or *Cathmul-Clark*. If the latter, it is essntially same techniques as for [keeping sharp edges with Subsurf](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface); Multires takes into account Mean Crease. The only difference is that if you beveled edges with modifier you have to apply it as Multires needs original data.