# How to get sharp red to blue in weight paint from vertex group

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

I am following [How to make towels](https://youtu.be/PEpsN1-W-Qw?t=22m48s) tutorial by BlenderGuru.

I can't seem to get that sharp red to blue that he does. My selection includes the full weight gradient (greens and yellows. view images). Is there a setting that I am missing? BTW - The vertex group is the whole mesh with weight set to 1, and the selections are set to a weight of 0.

Selection:
[image: Selection]

Weight Paint:
[image: Weight Paint]

UPDATE: adding [blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2380/) in case anyone wants to take a look at it. Note - the particle system was removed to reduce the file size

Comment: Do you have a subdiv modifier in place? That will add a blended weight around an otherwise clean selection... but just a guess.

Comment: And, if so, this may be of use: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: My current modifier stack is (top to bottom): SubSurf, Solidify, and Edge Split. Al l the same used within the tutorial. Unless he did something that that I missed, or wasn't shown, the setup is exactly the same as in the video. Oh and the particle system is sitting below all of those.

Comment: Sorry... away from bandwidth, but if you turn off SSDiv, do you get  a clean line?

Comment: I do. However it still isn't as sharp as the one in the tutorial. And I am pretty sure he still has his turned on when he sets the weight value. Currently re-watching to see if I missed anything.

Comment: So I re-watched, and don't see any point where he turns off subsurf. I did notice that my subsurf was set to 2 for render and preview. So I set it down to 1, like his. It removes the yellow, but I still have the green showing between.

Comment: Or maybe because you and he have a different Blender version? That's the only difference I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are correct - the sub-division represents it with gradient.

[image]

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer. I did a quick render and the particle system doesn't "fade" into the vertex group as I assumed it would based on the preview value. I guess it's just a mater of a step not being explained which caused my confusion. At the point in the tutorial where the weight is assigned, you cannot see what is set in the modifiers panel, so I assumed they remained the same.

Comment: Blender Guru spends a good deal of time making smooth productions of his videos and I would guess he edits to keep up the pace - he's had some criticism in the past for drawing out his tuts. Anyway see rcgauer should actually get the credit for pointing you in the right direction :)