# How do i get rid of the ugly cross splitting after seperating my faces

Tags: mesh

I'm making a Faceplate for my Self FNAF character and while trying to seperate the mouth plates from the head plates this problem happens. As you can see this is before i hit the Y button to seperate the mouth faces from the Top FacePlates[image: Before i hit y on selected faces][image: After i hit y on the selected faces.] And this is AFTER. i hit the y button to seperate. Do you notice how that looks just weird. I Dont want that, I Need it so it looks flat on the bottom of the top faceplates. But the top of the Mouth faceplates look like they do with Y pressed now.

Comment: If you mean that you'd like to get rid of smoothed curved corners of the mesh then delete Subsurf modifier from the stack. If you need it but only want mentioned part to stay sharp then see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: You need to change the order of your modifiers, the *Mirror* modifier should be on top, followed by the *Subsurf* afterwards

Answer (score 1):

you can create Edge Creases,

Shift + E in the two edges (marked by purple Line)
It should work

[image: Shift+E]

[Wiki about subdivision surface modifier and Edge Creases](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html)