# How to improve the prismatic approximations to the cylinders

Tags: modeling, rendering, edges

(I am a beginner)

Hi all, I would to know how to fix the prismatic approximations to the cylinders in my future renders.
What I mean is to fix the parts I've highlighted with a yellow highlighter in the following image:

[image]

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart setting mesh shading to smooth (which fakes roundness using normals, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html?highlight=smooth) you should probably learn about subdivision surface modifier (see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html), which creates new interpolated geometry in a non-destructive way (unless you apply the modifier, of course):

here you see a simple example: a simple basic cylinder, where you see the "prismatic approximation"

[image]

using the smooth shading you get something better (but it's just a smoothing faked, somehow):

[image]

instead you could use a subsurf modifier which creates the "missing geometry", depending on the subsurf level (here is 2)

[image]

since the subsurf "smooths" all, you get this weird result, but adding some "corrective" edge loop it gets better:

[image]

[image]

and you get this

[image]

which still has some lesser "prismatic approximation", but now the "smooth setting" works better

[image]

[image]

which is really quite smooth (and you can improve setting subsurf to 3, 4 or higher levels).

Of course your example image is more complex to "solve" because those are more complex object which only partly have cylindric sides.

You need to learn starting from simpler shapes, and experiment adding some edge loop as I did above, to keep some geometry "straight" and some "smooth" with control. The provided links have much info about this process, but believe me, you need to learn by yourself, failing many times, until you find the way.

You can also upload your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the resulting link editing the question, paste it in the text. Then we can help with your specific file and setup.

Comment: @Beatrix I replaced my previous animated gifs with simple images, it should be easier to see the effect. And lastly added some more hint on how to learn or get more help here.

Comment: I really thank you for the answer, BUT I didn't solve my problem.
I tried to read all your posted links, and apply "smooth" or "subsurface modifier", but here the results:
- my starting object [link](https://ibb.co/ht2Lca)
- smooth [link](https://ibb.co/fSORHa)
- my doubts about smooth (i can explain better if you are interested to help me ^^) [link](https://ibb.co/kz0j3F)
- subsurface 1views [link](https://ibb.co/g1eoVv)
- subsurface 3views [link](https://ibb.co/iNr2qv)
Thank you

Comment: oh sorry, I read now what you have replaced, I was writing my comment during your answer. I try to read better your answer now! Thankyou

Comment: @m. ardito WOW! Thankyou!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I solved! Loop Cut and Slide was the secret!!!! :D Thankyou so much!!!!!

Comment: @Beatrix WOW, that was quick, you got it really fast! Good, you will learn that this "trick" will always help you to improve basic geometric shapes, but sometimes it really needs practice and patience. Well done!

Comment: I read now you are from Turin! :D Me too! (do you give lessons or something similar?)

Comment: @Beatrix ! Really...? How funny. I never gave blender lessons, except some friend, but I'm always interested into helping others. This site is not much about messaging, even if there's a public chat available, but if you need, feel free to contact me on blenderartists.org, I'm m.ardito there, as well. Bye!