# Smoothing Problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I am pretty new to blender and 3D modelling.

I have this 'low poly wolf' head and I want to smooth it. But I think the geometry is very bad?

[image]

The geometry gets very strange when I do a subsurf:

[image]

I know that I can make the small details sharp with crease options. But some faces (for example the ones with the red arrow) have very strange shapes. Is there anyone who can help me with smoothing this object? Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload files used on the question and answers on this site. No adds, paywall or stuff like that to download.

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for informing me with this site! :) The file can be found here: [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3633/](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3633/)

Comment: Unfortunately, subsurf will give unexpected results when applying it to tris... which is what your entire mesh consists of.  See (among many others): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation/2939#2939

and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84455/smooth-shading-sub-surface-distorted-render/84539#84539

Answer (score 1):

This is a topology issue. 
The mesh is not at all optimized or even anywhere near qualified to be SubSurf'd
Looks like a result of non-traditional polymodeling techniques like Booleans or maybe exported from a freeform modeling application like Fusion360.

Ideally, you'd want your mesh to be of all quads with good flow to get a decent result with SubSurf. I won't go too into it right here, there's a hundred resources online if you want to read into this more.

This mesh is a mess in that regard. A lot of nasty spiders!

**So, what's the solution?**

Selecting everything and pressing ALT+J to convert Tris to Quads?
 No, because that will probably still not fix the fundamental issue with the mesh.

Only thing that would be a proper "answer" would be Manual Retopology, unfortunately. Try looking into BSurfaces or RetopoMT, read up on topology for SubD modeling and play around with it, then post your model and we can work it out together.

Have fun modeling :D

Answer (score 0):

Try removing **Subdivision Surface** modifier, select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> while in **Edit Mode**, press <kbd>W</kbd> and select **Smooth**.

Comment: Have you tried this method on this particular model or is it just a blind guess?