# Need help with sub surf weirdness

Tags: edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I cant seem to get rid of the ripples when making holes in my model.  The hole on the right has loop cut and I tried creaes.  Both hold have this weird small flap that keep showing up.

Here is the file if you want to look.[model with holes](https://app.box.com/s/txjvd42exrfsf8zepdt02ewhmwlmlpc0)

[image]

Comment: There's just not much you can do to combat tris and ngons.  There are many threads on BSE that address this.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84539/38953

Comment: In order to fix this you are going to need to clean up your mesh. There are a lot of ngons and tris all over the place. You mainly want to be working with quads when modelling things. Since it looks like you're working with boolean modifiers to cut those holes I'd recommend watching this tutorial by Andrew Price: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM

Answer (score 3):

As stated by @bertmoog this is result of bad topology. I will not elaborate on that as you have enough information in the link in comments, but I will show you how your topology should look like if you want to use **Subdivision Surface** modifier.

### Final result:

[image: Final]

I don't know how much do you know about modeling so I'll be brief, and if you need more info - ask in comments.

I've started with simple **Plane** with **Mirror** modifier on X and Y axes, extruded it upwards along your mesh. After that I've **Subdivided** it once and used **Inset** on top face. Then with **LoopTools** addon I've created **Circle** from vertices created by **Inset**, extruded it down and filed with **Grid Fill**, to achieve hard edges I've used **Bevel Tool** (not modifier).

Keywords marked with **Bold** should be enough for you to learn about this simple technique.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance...  I'm beginner with lots to learn.  Back to blender now.

Comment: @DeanWilliams If I may advice you, at the beginning don't take shortcuts. Learn proper method first, and after that try to use tools like Boolean. Also check here: http://topologyguides.com/