# Curved object wrinkled

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh

What can be causing these wrinkles?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Triangle faces. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the edges around your pole vertex, Ctrl-E, Subdivide, Select the resulting loop and shrink it so it's quite small and flatten it with the pole.