# Mesh in not straight any more, when I render it becomes rounded

Tags: rendering

Trying to make a simple cylinder

[image]

It looks fine in the object view, but then when I render it turns out weird, like this:

[image]

What do I do?

Comment: Remove the subsurf modifier

Comment: Or change the settings so that view and render are the same. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGATs.png

Comment: To mix smooth and straight edges read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: I want it to be a normal cylinder.. not look like a fennel seed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two settings for subdivision in the subsurf modifier (and other modifiers as well)

View determines the number of subdivisions for the viewport.

[image]

Render controls how many subdivisions it will have when you render.

It is designed that way so that the computer is not bogged with unnecessary computations while you work on the scene, and is more responsive while modeling, and then when you want to render you can have a smoother model.

Also, modifiers have switches that might be toggled for viewing and rendering. It is possible that one of the modifiers is disabled for viewing but is enabled for rendering.

[image]

The Camera icon enables or disables rendering using the modifier.

The Eye icon toggles visibility on the 3D viewport.