# subdivision surface modifier very weird behaviour

Tags: subdivision-surface, error

so this happens when I use the subdivision modifier. any explanation?

mesh without any other modifier:

[image]

after subdivision surface modifier:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: actually no it's a different issue

Comment: It is exactly the same issue. All you need to know is in gandalfs excellent answer. Your model lacks holding/supporting edges. Also you have huge n-gons that don't subdivide well (they get triangulated) on the front and back side of your model. A quick fix would be a bevel modifier before your subdiv modifier, but this only hides the topology inaccuracies. Look into basic modeling and topology tutorials and try to stick with quad only topology.