# How can I make a hollow cylinder faces to be smooth but not rounded just smooth?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: Hollow cylinder]

When I click on the left menu on Faces > Smooth it's making smooth but kind of rounded:

[image: Smooth rounded]

I want to keep it sharp as it was in the first screenshot but smooth.

Comment: Your question is not optimally worded. I guess your want to top thickness surface to have a sharp transition to the shell surface. For that you want to split the edge in top edges and side edge. You could achieve this, by adding an edge split modifier.

Comment: It *seems* that you want the same principles as here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface. You don't use Subsurf but still applies

Answer (score 1):

Smooth shading works by averaging the angle between two faces/edes/vertecies. This allows for smooth looks while keeping geometry low.

There are multiple ways to retain sharpness in a model:

1. Adding an edge split modifier. This will add additional geometry to mark edges sharp that are above a certain angle
2. Clicking on the "Vertex" tab on the right hand menu (it looks like a little updside-down triangle) You'll find an option to hit "Auto Smooth". This doesn't add any additional geometry and is my recommended way of going about this.
3. If you don't want to go with either of the two previous options then you can add a bevel modifier set to 0 width. This doesn't make a lot of sense and performs the same function as the edge split modifier.
4. You can mark individual geometry as "Sharp" by hitting CTRL + E and selecting "Mark Sharp"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is to make the top sharp, so to do that you need to create an edge loop (Ctrl R) Then orient the purple line so that it is horizontal. Left click, then move the line towards the top, it should smooth it out. If not you can reply

Comment: This would work a subsurf modifier screwing up the geometry, smooth shading will still look the same.