# How do you cut a clean hole into an object that has been subdivided?

Tags: subdivision-surface, knife-tool

I can't get it to work using any of the existing answers to this question. I have a box that has been subdivided.

[image]

I want to cut a square hole into it. I've tried using Knife Project and the Boolean modifier to cut the hole but I get the same kind of result. In both cases there are weird artifacts in the hole.

[image]

In the other questions about this type of problem they were saying something about how the subdivision modifier works better with quads but I'm not sure what that means. They were trying to cut circles and I'm trying to cut a square and a square has four points so I was hoping it would just magically be a quad or something.

Can you advise on how to cut this hole?

Comment: I doubt that you need that many subdivisions for such a simple object. Use smooth shading and no more than 3 subdivisions on subsurf. Quads are polygons with 4 vertices, and yes try to use quads. Then the question for you is what shape are you expecting out of the "hole" a straight cut or a circluar one?

Comment: Here it seems that the boolean modifier is set before the subdivision. Try to invert that: place the subdivision modifier before. If using knife project (or other cut), you'll need to apply the subdivision firt.

Comment: If you are learning blender **try to avoid boolean operations as much as you can** and learn proper modeling. Watch this video: [8 ways of cutting holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA).

Comment: Following the comment by @cegaton, yes you should use bevel instead of subdivision modifier. That will round the edges without adding to many geometry in the faces.

Comment: @lemon, tried it but I'm still getting the same thing.

Comment: @cegaton, The model is for 3D printing so I don't think a shader will do the trick. 

Comment: There is no need to have that many subdivisions on flat surfaces... bevels would work fine. And the question still stands: what shape are you expecting out of the "hole" a straight cut or a circluar one?

Comment: The hole should be completely straight. I just like the rounding effect that the subdivisions give. I guess I could try a different modifier. Bevel looked okay but I liked how doing subdivisions looked better.

Comment: So, concerning your last comment: use the boolean after the subdivision. And use a cube to make the hole.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to print it, you'll need to have a manifold geometry (so not this hole that is shown in the picture in your question)

Comment: To have straight edges while keeping subsurf use creases and/or supporting edges. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface Also, if the model is to be 3d printed you need thickness to have manifold geometry(as pointed out by @lemon)

Comment: Allright, for this particular problem I can actually get it to look the same way with Bevel now that I mess with it enough. I just locked on to doing it with subdivisions and couldn't think of anything else. Thanks for your help folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When 'they' say subdivision surface works best with quads, they mean that if you can get your pre-subdiv model to only use quad faces, you get a better result. Generally you would want to make the hole before applying the subdivision modifier.
[image]

[image]

To avoid 'cutting circles', you need to add supporting geometry around edges that you want to 'harden'. There are many ways to go about this. You can do it manually by simply adding additional edge loops and sliding them into place.

[image]

You could also use a bevel modifier above your subdivision modifier in the stack.

[image]