# How to cut out the part of mesh and add geometry to it without broken topology?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

I want to achieve that and apply subdivision surface on that mesh:
[image]

I can easy do that with boolean modifier and topology looks great, but after that I can't add additional geometry on that mesh. Even with "simple" option of subdiv it generate additional details.[image]
I tried just to add loop cuts, but it doesn't work too:
[image]
I tried to add subdiv and then cut out part of mesh, but can't do anything with it:
[image]

Can you help me with it?

Comment: Can you show the topology of the object before applying sub-d?

Comment: You can see it on 3 screenshot. Or you need it with vertex mode enabled?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144500/how-do-you-cut-a-clean-hole-into-an-object-that-has-been-subdivided https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126789/subdivision-surface-modifier-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have double vertices which are either overlapping each other, or your normals are inverted incorrectly. You also have an Ngon on the top and bottom faces and need to use the knife tool (K) to resolve it.
The image below should show how your topology should look.
[image]
To fix both of these problems you can try merging by distance, and then closely zooming in on affected vertices and moving them around with (G) to make sure theyre properly joined.

To fix bad normals you will need to select the entire object in edit mode (A) and then go to mesh>Normals>Recalculate outside.

Also, considering how simple the object seems, what you do need subdivision for it?

Comment: You're absolutely right! There was a problem with normals on the last screen and knife helped with the situation on the 3 screen. about your question: there is a building, so I need subdivision for additional details, like foundation, roof, battlement and other things. Thank you!