# How to smooth only one side of the model?

Tags: modeling

I have this medallion thing. Which i made from a png and i need to smooth only one side of it. Is there a way to accomplish this? Other than modelling it from scratch.

[image: Description in image for better understanding.]

Comment: it's not clear what you want to smooth, if you're talking about the edges all over the top, use some bevels

Comment: Probably you're talking about Smooth shading, enable it in the object properties. If it smoothens up too much enable AutoSmooth angle or EdgeSplit modifier. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One side of the coin as in top and bottom? If so you can extrude the bottom faces and apply "Smooth vertice" then apply "shade smooth" but only with those bottom faces. To do this you have to be in edit mode and only select the faces that you want make smooth. [image: This is done here]

[image]
[image]