# Car Modeling Subsurf Modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface, bevel, artifacts

I am now trying to model my first sports car in blender.
I am pretty happy for the first attempt, but I have a few problems with keeping some edges sharp and subsurf others.
Currently I am using an solidify modifier, a bevel modifier and at the bottom a subsurface on level 2.
The bevel modifier helps with keeping sharp edges but makes some weird artifacts.
I have attached some images (first with bevel modifier, second without and 3rd of the artifacts), if needed I can also upload the file.
Thanks for your help :)

[image: With Bevel Modifier]

[image: Without Bevel Modifier]

[image: Artifact]

[image: Mesh]

[image: Mesh 2]

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the mesh in edit mode as the artifacts are caused by the mesh topology. Have you tried assigning bevel weight/crease weight to your edges? Check this post out, has some great tips that might help.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: Sorry that I respond so late, thanks for your tips, but that didn't really help. Or I was just too stupid to use them ;). I have attached 2 images of my mesh to the original post :)

Comment: Have you tried adding some loops cuts near the artifacts to give it a little more geometry to work with?

Comment: I have now beveled the edges where this problem occurred and this worked :) I additionally have a question for modeling cars. Since it's the first I am modeling, would you subsurf it or not? :) Because subsurface makes some problems but also makes it a little easier, so I wanted to ask what's the way to go? :)

Comment: Yes, you'll want to use subsurface eventually but you'll serve yourself better in the long run if you focus on good topology on your model. When I'm building my models I generally work in low poly for as long as I can before adding subsurface. I can't emphasize enough how important this is, especially if you're still learning. Check out this great site which has a lot of great info about good topology. https://topologyguides.com/

Comment: Also, check out this video from Flipped Normals which has some good points on the subject too. https://youtu.be/F06n6VmNEio

Comment: And another, specific to car modeling. https://www.ebalstudios.com/blog/modeling-cars-polygons