# How to get rid of corners rounding on blender?

Tags: faces

I'm a beginner with blender and not sure why my corners are rounding off? I would like them to create a square face, I've added reference images below. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't want rounding when using a Subdivision Surface modifier, you need to supporting geometry (ex: loop cuts). See here for more - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199262/75504

Comment: yea, if you don't want rounded edges, add loop cuts in edit mode and slide them super close to the edge to get ride of rounded edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape has a subdivision surface modifier.

A possible way to obtain sharp corners is to change the way this modifier uses the edges with "*edge crease*", <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

- Go in edge select mode
- Select the surrounding edges
- And use edge crease

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! All these solutions have worked great.

Comment: Hi! If that solves your issue, please consider to accept the answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thanks @KerriO'Shea