# how to specify what to subdivide

Tags: objects, subdivision-surface

[image]

my character that i have models is one object, i want to subdivide the head and other body parts, however i dont know how to keep the one i want with sharp edges to stay

[image]

i want to keep the mouth the way it is, sharp, i dont know how to, can anyone help me

Comment: you can select the parts you want and right click > Subdivide. If you're talking about the Subdivision Surface modifier, it will affect the whole mesh, but you can find some ways to keep some of your angles sharp, like adding edge loops, Bevel modifier, etc...

Comment: Related (if you use subdivision surface modifier) [Keep Sharp Edges when Using Subdivision Surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface)