# Smooth Shading on specifically-oriented edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I have a spherically tapered cylinder that I'm trying to apply smooth shading to, partially.  (Sorry for the terrible description, picture below)

[image]

I'm trying to apply smooth shading to vertical rings in the picture - I like the defined edges that run along the x-axis.  I tried selecting only those rings in edit mode and applying smooth vertex, but that didn't appear to do anything.  Will, I have to put in loop cuts for each x-axis line, then add an edge split with smooth shading to get my desired effect?

Comment: No need for loop cuts, just use mark sharp.

Comment: Related: [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/D11#comment-26) ([will be in blender 2.71](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Modeling)), blender has support for split normals. You can download 2.71 release candidate 2 [here](http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/graphics/blender/release/Blender2.71/).

1. Set your object to smooth shading.
2. Enable *auto smooth* in *Properties > object data*:

   [image]
3. Select every edge loop and mark it as sharp:

   1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> on one of edge loops you want to make sharp to select that edge ring.
   2. Press *Edge Loop* in *3D view > Header > Select* to select the rest of the loops.
   3. Press *Sharp* in *3D view > Tool shelf > Shading / UV > Shading > Edges*, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>*> Mark Sharp*:

      [image]

### Result:

[image]

Comment: You really ARE Gandalf - the Gandalf of blender.  Like... a wizard... like... that sounded better in my head.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to wait for 2.71 ! It has custom normals, so you'll be able to specify which edges are sharp, which ones are smooth. As of now we can't except with an edgesplit modifier which is destructive. Wait a few days ! ;)

Hadrien

Comment: As long as you don't apply it, an edge split modifier won't do anything to your base mesh.