# Strange light artifact

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I'm trying to make a realistic render, but I'm having some troubles with lights and reflections
[image]
In this scene I have three lights around the object, the trouble is in the corners. I can't find why the reflection is not uniform across both parts of the meshes.
Is the same object with two meshes, the entire object has the same material and I'm using the Blender Render (not cycles) and ambient occlusion. (Also applied "smooth" to the lateral faces)

Comment: Glad you dropped by.  Unfortunately there is a problem with your question.  There is not a lot to go on here.  While there is a decent chance that several people will offer guesses, and that one of them may be correct, it would be much better if you put more effort into documenting what you've done so far so that people have a better idea of what's actually taking place here.  For instance, you could show a scrrencapture of the model in various modes like smooth-shaded and wire-frame.  It would also help if you activated the normals display and showed a picture of how that looks.

Comment: It could be that you just have to enter Edit mode, select all the faces and press Ctrl-n to Recalculate Normals.  It also could be that you have interior faces which are throwing off the smoothing calculations.  Or maybe you have to select all the vertices and press 'w' -> Remove Doubles.  You can also upload the .blend file to a hosting service like PasteAll.org so people can examine it for errors.  Usually this gets the best results for solving the problem quickly.

Comment: Since this is about guessing.\: I I'd say that your issue has to do with the kind of lights you are using and where they are placed... but I have no images to back my claim, so it might as well be something else entirely different. Please post more information or your blend file.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'll do more research about how these reflections have been created and hope to find the answer. (Also Here is the link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f66ux1ir2gno8g2/DOMOCRACY.blend?dl=0 if anyone could catch the trouble in the fly) Thanks again

Comment: Use the Edge split modifier as described in this answer [http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734...](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/735#735). Possible duplicate of [http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734...](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/)

Comment: Also, you have some edges marked sharp on the round phase. Might need to delete the edge flags or untick Sharp Edges in the Edge Split modifier.