# Edges with mean crease set to 1 are still rounded by a subsurf modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am a complete beginner in blender, so my question may turn out to be trivial.

I have a cylinder with some square-ish elements slightly carved into it, as you can see in this screenshot

[image: as you can see in this screenshot]

All of the edges of the squares have a mean crease value of 1:
[image]
However when i apply a subsurf modifier the result looks like this

[image: like this].

What should I do to keep the edges straight when applying the modifier?

Comment: Hmm, rereading your question, you say all the edges are creased. Can you post a screenshot in _Edit_ mode so I can remove or update my answer accordingly.

Comment: you need to crease the inner corner edges.

Comment: @iKlsR: done, as you wrote the problem were the inner edges, thanks for the quick answer and the bonus tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the inner edges are creased at the corners as well. For example:

### With only outer edges creased

[image]

### With inner edges creased

[image]

As a bonus, you might want to drop an *Edge Split* modifier on as well to get your object smooth and remove the stretched shades that creasing and subsurf will produce. Also see [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/734/12).

[image]