# Should I avoid triangles when doing retopology?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm having an extremely difficult time avoiding triangles when doing retopology. Is it even necessary to do so?

The only way I can see to easily avoid them it have have many more polygons than necessary...

Making a game asset for UE4

[image]

Comment: Please show an image of your work so we better understand your question.

Comment: Although question 43377 is slightly different, my answer [43378](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43377/sub-surf-and-triangles/43378#43378) applies just as well here as it does there. The essence: convert one of the vertices of a triangle to a zero length edge. Then, even though it looks like a triangle, it is a quad.

Comment: Sorry should have added pic!

And thanks for the answer brasshat, but I'm unable to figure out what you mean. How do I convert an edge to zero length?

Comment: If you rip a vertex (v-key), you create two vertices which have the same position. Box- or circle-select both of the vertices, or duplicate the original vertex, and select both the original vertex and the ripped or duplicated one, and create an edge. Because the two vertices have the exact same co-ordinates, the "edge" will have a zero length, but as analyzed by Blender when using loop cuts, &c., those tools which require a quad to work properly will work properly, and it will be a quad, even if it looks like a tri.

Comment: In this case you may be fine with tris, because it's a solid model that will not need to deform. But there are many cases when you will need to be able to model something with all-quads or almost-all-quads. Topology is a really extensive topic, so I recommend you start by reading [this](http://panoptic.com/rking/blender/GEN_SubD-ThreadHighlights.pdf).