# Need help with creased edges connected to uncreased with subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling

I am fairly new to blender and have a few questions about creases and subsurf.

On this helmet, I am trying to give the visor area a hard edge, but doing so with the subsurf modifier makes the visor bulge out because the rest of the mesh moves inward as it is subdivided.

Here it is with subsurf on: [image: link]

Here it is with subsurf off: [image: link]

Front: [image: link]

This is for animation and gaming, so I am trying to avoid being too high poly (subsurf is turned up to clarify my problem)

Heres the blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/42941

Comment: I'm confused with the "This is for animation and gaming" part. Are you planing to use this mesh in a game? If so why do you have a subdivision modifier on it (even at level 1)?

Comment: Related (possible duplicates): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42264/how-to-get-hard-edges-when-using-subsurf-modifier and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18465/edges-with-mean-crease-set-to-1-are-still-rounded-by-a-subsurf-modifier/18467#18467

Comment: With models for gaming I make a high-poly version of the mesh and bake the normal map in Substance to apply it to a low-poly version of the mesh.  The deformation caused by the subsurf modifier is not covered in the two linked questions and if this problem is not fixable I will just apply the modifier when I am done and reshape it but I was trying to save myself some work.

If someone could actually look at the blend I would appreciate it.

Comment: why don't you simply move the visor vertices to the inside so that they don't bulge out any more ?

Answer (score 2):

Well... bulging out to not bulging out :

[image]

Comment: You could just smoothen those 4 vertices with *Smooth* from `W` menu.

Comment: @MrZak, yes... the point here was more about 'what was the question' (considering its comments)... but you are right

Comment: Yes, I've got what could be the problem from your answer provided that screenshots do not emphasize anything.