# Hard surface modeling on cylinder

Tags: modeling, geometry

So, I want to add some details to cylinder and I've been struggling with this for awhile and can't find a proper way to do this.

First method on the image is with autosmooth and this is basicly what I want but I need also to use node geometry > pointiness which isn't working as needed.

Second with subsurf and some loop cuts gives me good looking pointiness but the shape of this detail isn't what I am looking for. When I'm trying to add more loop cuts to hardness the edges cylinder is breaking (horizontal bulge under this element, or vertical strip along whole cylinder).

I've tried adding small bevel on edges, high density base model and what not. This driving me crazy.

Any ideas how to make it right?

[image: What I get so far]

### UPDATE:

Here it's a blend file:
[image]

### UPDATE 2:

Method proposed by @Róbert László Páli is by far most correct, I need to check how this will behave with PBR Metallic material, because there are some geometry, I don't know, glitches?

[image: Glitches]

### UPDATE 3:

I've tried it with some PBR material and sadly it's visible with light reflection.

[image: PBR]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Darth Maul Lightsaber.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. What exactly is the problem, what exactly do you need help with, and what exactly do you hope to achieve in the specific area that you need help with.

Comment: I'm trying to make it look like in autosmooth example (hard edges) with pointiness like in Subsurf example. All this info is in my post.

Comment: Ok, now I get you. Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: I've added it below question.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges - and - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18465/edges-with-mean-crease-set-to-1-are-still-rounded-by-a-subsurf-modifier/18467#18467

Comment: @cegaton I know them. It's not what I'm asking. Pointiness want work well with edge split and autosmooth. Even with beveled edges.

Comment: Hey, I too hate those glitches, and their is not too much to do with those, but seem my new edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edge Crease

Use the subsurf, but insted of loop cuts, select the sharp edges, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd> which will make the crease of those edges one.

## Advice

Instead of autosmooth, you could use smooth shading and an edge split modifier after the subsurf. If you select both angle based and sharp edge splitting, you can add additional sharp edges by selecting them and marking them sharp at the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> menu.

## Edit One

The edge split actually messes up the pointiness. You can use the auto sharp as originally.

[image: Creased Subdivision]

## The Blend

[image]

## Edit Two

[image: Geometry Glitch]

The edge crease - besides retaining the sharpness of the inset - also makes those edges not going little deeper, where they should. This is demonstrated by this simple circle:

[image: Demonstartion]

You can start from a higher resolution cylinder to make those glitches less apparent. The higher the resolution of the base mesh, the less that glitch is visible:

[image: High Resolution]

[image: Less Glitch]

Note: The mesh density at the part where you want to use the pointyness is important, other loop cuts may be  removed. I have also updated the Blend.

Comment: This isn't working at all. Look at the blend file.

Comment: I think this method is pretty good, look at UPDATE 2 for details. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Now everything is good as should be. Thanks for great effort!