# Using pointiness and bevel at same time

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm making a chair and trying to use pointiness attribute to express the damage of paint at the edges. However the chair has bevel so when I put the bevel on, the corner gets rounder and the pointiness disappear. Is there anyway I can use pointiness as if there was no bevel?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check my question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60710/hard-surface-modeling-on-cylinder as it may not seems to be related, it is covering some pointiness issue which should apply to your question. You can upload your model to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ it will be easier to provide good answer.

Comment: This is not possible :-(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, I don't think there is a good way to do this.

As far as I know the *Pointiness* atribute relies on actual final geometry to work, thus can' be faked if the geometry is not really sharp.

For this specific shape You could try and fake it with a gradient texture centered of the object. It's an approximation, but with a little tweaking may achieve good results.

Just add a *Gradient* node connected to the *Generated* socket and adjust its positioning with a *Vector* node by [-0.05,-0.05,-0.05]. You can use a *Color Ramp* to adjust the progression.

You may also combine by color-mixing several different linear gradients to achieve an effect of a gradient starting from every edge.

[image]

Comment: Right thank you for the idea! Maybe that is little too focued on the corner rather the edges. might be better if I draw texture for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not this is what exactly what I wanted, but if I put subsurf under bevel, the damages shows up little.

[image]