# Cut rounded corner holes from a face of a cube

Tags: mesh

I'm new to Blender. The problem statement is: there is a cube and we have to cut multiple rounded corner rectangular holes from the face of the cube.

Actually there are many tutorials regarding how to cut circles from faces/planes. But, could not make out how to cut rounded corner rectangular shapes from those.

Please help.

Comment: I just did it, by I think in a very crud manner. Added one cube mesh. Rounded it's corner edges. Used Boolean modifier and difference with the actual Cube's one of the faces. It serves the purpose. But, I think there should be a good process to do this.

Comment: Check question I've asked a while ago: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60710/hard-surface-modeling-on-cylinder