# Smooth shaded model has odd shading

Tags: modeling, edges

I'm currently working on a model of an X-wing that I'm intending for use in a game and running into a bit of trouble with the shading of the mesh. The upper nose is rounded off where the sensor cone attaches, but at the point it reaches the canopy frame it flattens out and meets at a corner.

Everything is fine and dandy when the sides are modeled:

[image]

but once I close it off and add the top of the nose, the shading goes to hell:

[image]

As you can see, the smoothing gets confused at the lip of the cockpit.

I've tried a couple different means of getting around this, none of which looks right while maintaining the correct shape. The transition from the rounded to flat is a fairly important part of the ship's character, so I don't want to discard the contours, either.

Any tips or suggestions on modeling this area?

Addendum:

If I eliminate that second angle where the canopy frame meets the fuselage as marked in red:

[image]

this also fixes the smoothing. However this is not a solution, as the angle is a part of the design. It DOES give me another thought on fixing, but I won't be able to test it until I get home.

Comment: After writing an answer and editing the title I noticed that this is arguably a duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges?rq=1 but I think it's ok to have a more general answer for this.

Comment: Normals>Average (after recalculating outside if needed) if all else fails, also check for overlapping verticies/edges/faces, join whenever you can, mark sharp edges *sometimes* helps but generally that should work on its own. And of course, if they look backwards after the fact just flip them.  Generally what happens is faces get mucked up from adding in angled edges where a flat plane once was, average usually fixes this without fail. Always APPLY all transformations before doing anything like bevels, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because your mesh edges change direction sharply. It's unavoidable by default unless you add supporting geometry to make the transition smoother.

The image below shows 3 similar cylinders that were smooth shaded. The first has a ngon capping the top, the second is capped with triangles and the last has a ngon cap but has a bevel around the edge. Notice that the 3rd cylinder doesn't have any weird shading since we eliminated the sharp edge.

[image]

So to fix, add supporting geometry by beveling your edges to avoid sharp curves and turns.

*Another* fix is to just add an *Edge Split* modifier. The cylinder on the left is the default one shaded smooth, the other one has the modifier. This won't always just work out of the box though for more complicated shapes and might require some tweaking.

[image]

Comment: I already have the Edge Split modifier applied. I've also tried adding a bevel and I just haven't found a way to do that that doesn't alter the shape too much.

Comment: @Ambaryerno Share the model so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Mesh is here: http://wyrmfyrforge.net/Uploads/X-Wing_FuselageTrouble.blend

I've removed out everything but the offending section for size and simplicity.

Comment: @Ambaryerno This is because of pinching, you can't have that many points ending at one pole in space and not expect any artefacts. The tris are causing that. rework them and it should smooth out.

Comment: I made a few adjustments and got it to a point where it didn't require a significant reworking of the mesh around the cockpit. Since the canopy is all hard edges, anyway, cheating by marking a couple extra sharp edges to maintain the shading was much less noticeable there.

Thanks for all the feedback. This is proving a more and more complex build the more clear references I find. :-P

Comment: @Ambaryerno I had a few minutes to spare, have a look at this and note the difference. Yours is the one on the left, the one on the right is just smooth shaded, nothing else added, look at the lines. http://pasteall.org/blend/33942. When doing hardsurface modeling and even more so organic, try to avoid pinching so many tris together. If you have quads, it makes it easier to add detail later.

Comment: Yeah, I'd tried something like that already, the problem is that on the actual effects model the corners of where the canopy frame meet the fuselage do come to a hard corner, while this example carries the rounded top all the way back. Like I said, I was able to get something that works by remodeling a few things and putting a very fine bevel at the corner.

Answer (score 4):

As [mentioned by iKlsR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23597/599), this is caused by blender trying to smooth the normals over a sharp edge.

To avoid this, you can also use [split normals](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Modeling).
Split normals behave basically like the edge split modifier, but without actually splitting edges and creating double vertices.

To use it, enable *Autosmooth* in *Properties > Object Data > Normals* and tweak the *Angle* as you would with an edge split modifier:

[image]

You can also manually mark specific edges, vertices, or faces to be sharp:

[image]

Comment: The problem is when I try to mark a vertex as sharp, it applies it to the ENTIRE edge (and in fact, ALL edges that touch that vertex) even when I only select a single vertex to mark. Autosmooth I run into the same issue: When tweaking the angle, it turns the entire edge sharp, not just the vertex.

Comment: For what it's worth (blender v3.4) I found that using Normals>Average face area fixed all my  problems with the "creasing" effect you get when adding varied angles of sharpness to an object, such as going from/to a bevel from a flat surface, or areas where mesh transforms have been used heavily.  This is my go-to fix for most of those problems--an artist should never have to manually edit surface normals themselves, nor should they have to go through and select every edge unless they are making some object that defies the laws of known reality.  Note this does not include normal "trickery".