# Blender FBX import issue - normals/shading

Tags: mesh, export, import

I imported a fbx file (a car) to blender and the shadows on the mesh get crazy. Can some one tell me why and how I can import without this mess shadows destroying the 3d Art.

here is a image of the problem:
[image: image of the problem]

Comment: try fixing your normals. In edit mode, select all (A) and Ctrl+N (recalculate normals)

Comment: As a rule, blenders FBX import-export doesn't work :/

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23596/12

Comment: all faces is selected and Ctrl+N and nothing happend no magic there :(

Comment: @GiantCowFilms There's a reason for that... Basically, the official implementation of FBX is _not_ open source, and thus, cannot be included in Blender, unless it was distributed under another license

Comment: See GiantCowFilms comment. Try another format for import/export

Comment: Try removing doubles in Blender.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I’d like not to see such stupidity… FBX IO, especially of non-rigged meshes, works nearly perfectly (and remaining issues are being addressed).

Comment: @mont29 I don't think the insult is warranted, but no worries, my skin is somewhat thick by now (I can assure you it is thicker then my skull :P). Although you say *most* of the issues have been addressed, we get way more FBX export issues here then any other format. Futhmore, I've personally had a lot of trouble with blenders FBX, and I no longer use it.

Comment: i like everything with blender without this Import/export it is a little broken if u ask me a use 3DS max to but don't like it but there is never a problem with import/export :/ noone knows if i can get this "car" in whitout this mess ? i only have fbx fil on this a export in other format and get the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your FBX file more than likely uses custom normals.

Up to a one week ago, this was not supported at all by Blender, so custom normals were lost during import and you would get that ugly shading.

This has been fixed (added!) now in Blender master, please try it with an official build from [the buildbot](https://builder.blender.org/download).

Comment: Okay, so FBX works, oh but you need to get a highly volatile poorly tested build from a place that hardly anyone knows about. That *isn't* working, I'm glad to see improvements, don't get me wrong, I'm very grateful for contributions from you and others, just don't defend features that aren't in an official release. My comment came from being burnt many times in the past and even with 2.72 (last time I tired to suffer through FBX with blender).

Comment: i gonna try it now

Comment: @GiantCowFilms please stop trolling about things you do not know about (quoting: “I no longer use it”).

Comment: THAT's IT it work thx you :)

Comment: \*Sigh\* I *do* use them about once or twice per release, and although I don't have a developers knowledge about the tool, I *do* know it isn't working like the ones in other packages I use form time to time...

Comment: What are u saying ? it work 4 me this i dont get that shadow mess now

Comment: @Adde We are disagreeing about my dislike of the FBX tools supported in the *current release*... the answer is perfectly valid though

Comment: yes okej. if you are going to discuss about things, like u do now, so visit a forum or something instead :) ty

Comment: Let's say you can use a not stable official release from builbot.blender.org or another file format for import/export (suggestion needed)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem. I am using Blender 2.82 official. Importing an FBX file from Modo. The shading nromals where horrible. I found by selecting your part and going into edit mode, select all faces then go into the Mesh Menu - Normals - Set From Faces. Fixes all shading errors. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when i import unity asset fbx model, i find the solution:

- download maya lt
- maya import this fbx
- (optional) import model material in maya
- in maya, export this model to .obj file
- and in blender import this .obj file
  it work in my case