# Triangulation artifacts

Tags: modeling, modifiers, artifacts

After triangulation I've got these shading artifacts. how do I get rid of them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post a wire frame screenshot. Are you using sub-surf?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xIR6J6k.png

Comment: Your topology is a bit of a mess and its tough to tell if all the faces are planer. If they are, you could try the edge split modifier along that back edge. See this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23597/26720