# How do I prevent weird shadow clusters on curved surfaces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, geometry, shadows

I am trying to make a rather complex surface (as pictured) but find that my geometry is making weird shadows. I've already recalculated and checked normals and vertices alignment. Any advice would be appreciated!

[image]

Project file: https://we.tl/t-FEEFF9Trmf

Comment: Hello :). I believe these threads could help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23596/78972, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/734/78972