# Some areas of the mesh are dark (Shadow artefacts)

Tags: rendering, lighting

I've been modeling a hermit crab and I don't know why but some areas of the mesh are really dark on some spots, like the legs and the claws.
[image]

I hope you can help me fix it.

Comment: Try to select all mesh in Edit Mode and press Ctrl+N to Make Normals Consistent... did it help?

Comment: I've already try that it didn't work

Comment: can you upload your .blend via this link so I can take a look at it?
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called shadow terminator artifact and happens with some render engines on low poly meshes. It is a limitation that Cycles has, devs know about it.

[Bug T37814: Artifacts in Cycles render for lowpoly models](https://developer.blender.org/T37814)

[image]

[image]

The solution is to increase the polygon count.

The black on the silhouette is another kind of artifacts you might encounter called rejection sampling - also does go away with polycount.

You can change also the shading method. Your whole surface is set to smooth - it is interpolating the surface normals making shadows where there probably shouldn't be. You may want to turn on Auto-smooth or set some sharp edges:

[How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8720/7777)

Answer (score 0):

Also, when rendering with Eevee, check if **Contact Shadows** option for your Light source is on. This option tends to give similar edgy-looking shadows in render, even with Subdivision Surface.

Answer (score 0):

Since Blender 2.9 you can now easily fix the **Terminator Effect** that you show, just tweak the *Shadow Terminator Offset* value in the *Properties panel > Object > Shading*:

[image]