# Normal Map bad shading in Rendered display

Tags: normal-map

I have a *Normal Map* problem: I've baked a high-poly sphere to a low-poly, but whatever I try there's always a bad shading on the surface of the low-poly in *Rendered* display, between the light and the shadow. It disappears if I unplug the *Normal Map*. What am I doing wrong? Is it inevitable? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Solved by Serge, it looks like it's the *terminator* issue, **fixed with a bigger light size**. Answer also given [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/issue-with-normal-maps-on-character/701862/4) by IkariShinji, and as Leander pointed out, [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/cycles-shadows-on-smooth-shaded-mesh-strange-behavior) by Crazycourier.

file: [image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like *terminator* problem

Comment: wow you're right and it seems like the solution is to increase a bit the light size, thanks a lot, please give an answer so that it can be considered as solved. It took me the day to understand  :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some areas of the mesh are dark](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/some-areas-of-the-mesh-are-dark). [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1998/30849) and [related (autosmooth)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27982/30849).

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, Crazycourier answers correctly in your second link when he talks about light setups, in my case the solution won't be to Smooth shading (it's already smoothed), nor increase the topology (it would ask a very high level of subdivision and anyway it would make no sense in that case, Normal Map is used to avoid high-topology), nor Auto-smooth (doesn't work), but increase the light size.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Terminator** issue hasn't got a proper solution for *Cycles* yet. Increasing Lamp's size makes penumbra bigger and issue becomes less visible.

Size setting is here:

[image]