# Smooth shading not so smooth?

Tags: shaders, lighting, artifacts

I don't understand why I see these edges when rendering my model. They don't appear in object mode, but when I render.

[image]

[image]

And the topology seems dense enough to not produce these edges?

Here are some images of the topology and lighting, which is only an hdri of a photo studio:

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe it's the same problem as the one I've met yesterday: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139205/normal-map-bad-shading-in-rendered-display

Comment: @moonboots Ah, I had that problem with another project where I used a normal map as in your case:/ Guess I’ll try tweaking the lights

Comment: Is your Object's shading set to Smooth? (or Flat?) Is Autosmooth on?

Comment: @a-tokarev yes, it’s smooth shaded and no I haven’t tried autosmooth. I am using the edge split modifier, because I want the tail to be flat shaded