# Flat shading due to normal map. Why?

Tags: shaders, normals, normal-map

I'm making a simple sweater for my model. I've added normal map node, set texture to "non-color", baked normal map from Multries without any polygon artifacts and I got this:
[image]
[image]

*Shade Smooth* is On, *Auto Smooth* is off. *Non-Color* was set before baking as well.

It does not depends on this saturated pink-green colors, polygons appear on a whole mesh. I tried to make NM in a new file but it has the same problem.

I used Blender 3.0, 3.1 and even 2.93. Also checked on my laptop. I [saw](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139205/normal-map-bad-shading-in-rendered-display) that strong lightning can hide it but it doesn't solve the problem anyway. Hope someone knows how to get rid of this.

[image]

Comment: I can't see any problems in the normal map and since I don't see any other settings apart from the material, it's hard to guess what other reasons there could be. It would be best to provide the blend file. Or check the _Object Data Properties_ tab for _Geometry Data_. If there is a button "Clear Custom Split Normals Data", then click it.

Comment: Attached. But, as I said, it also happens in default files (on different PCs), although everything was good until this moment.

Comment: Whose kind of areas indicates that you really had some issues with baking. Whey are too bright for typical normal map [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuuDM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuuDM.png)

Comment: This could be a reason. I'm not an expert in normal maps, but if they are way too bright and that in combination with a _Strength_ of 5 in the _Normal Map_ node (screenshot says 1, but the file I downloaded has 5), this might be an issue. But I cannot really test anything because the normal map is not packed into the file.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes, but it is in post as image

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to change it again to 1 because I was testing different strengthes. But if you set it to 1 and upload the picture above I think you will see the same result. There's more saturated polygons on the whole mesh when I change the strength. And I don't think the problem is bright parts of the normal map. Yes, flat shading is more shown in this parts but it can also be seen on the others. I also tried to bake random lines I made in multries (it had no bright parts) and there was flat shading anyway.

Comment: There is only one sweater object in the file (and no multires modifier attached) so we can't try to work on a solution related to the baking.

Comment: Try setting the color space of the texture node to "Linear" instead of "Non-Color"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case the problem was a blender version. I downloaded 2.83.14 (I cleaned all the previous settings in `AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83` before), added subdivided cube and baked simple normal map - everything looks nice. If I open the same file in the latest version it shows polygons again:
[image]

[image]

If someone has such a problem I suggest to download another version of blender. But I also noticed that you need to create mesh in this version instead of the newest one, otherwise it will have flat shading. But I still don't think it is a right solution. (resetting blender >2.93 also didn't changed anything)

Comment: There is definitely something wrong, and probably with the scene itself considering how exporting the model  I.E. as fbx magically "fixes" the issue. Do you happen to have started working on 3.x and then went on an older Blender version?