# Cycles high angle face artefact

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

I have a sun lamp at 90 degrees to a curved mesh. In Eevee, the shadow renders as smooth. However, in Cycles, I get these black artefacts - entire faces on the shadow edge are black.

How do I fix this? I've played around with the mesh normals, material settings, etc. No luck.

[image]

**Update**
I fixed this with Subsurf modifier. Is there a better way?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/cycles-shadows-on-smooth-shaded-mesh-strange-behavior https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/some-areas-of-the-mesh-are-dark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Shadow Terminator Offset***

you can find this setting in
Properties ‣ Object Properties ‣ Shading

increase it to 0.15 which is really enough

Note: this is a new feature came in blender 2.90 so you need to update blender to some newer version

[image]
[image]

> Note
>
> This property artificially alters the scene’s lighting and is not
> energy conserving and consequently not physically accurate.

Got from the blender Manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/render/cycles/object_settings/object_data.html#shading