# Some shadows are too sharp in the render

Tags: shadows

do you know what is causing this type of shadows? Does it have something to do with the way the mesh is?
[image]

[image]

Comment: delete some edge loops to see if it fixes your problem

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p