# Cycles render UV Sphere problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Anyone comes across similar problem?
[image: blender cycles render uv sphere]

Comment: This is called the shadow terminator problem. See: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4986/ray-tracing-shadows-the-shadow-line-artifact
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p
Issue reported on the bug tracker: https://developer.blender.org/T37814

Comment: increase your light size (called angle in 2.8 I guess) a bit