# How to keep flat faces flat when using smooth shading

Tags: normals

Is there a way to make a smooth shaded mesh look like the third column in this example? The six sides of the cube should have their vertex normals aligned with the face normal.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Beveled, smooth shaded (faces are not flat)
2. beveled, smooth shaded, edge split (faces aren't joined)
3. Modified in external application (faces are flat, bevels are smooth)

[image: Example]

Comment: Possible dupe http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/734/12

Comment: @iKlsR Even following the suggestions in that question I can't seem to get a result like the OP's third example here.

Comment: @gandalf3 First seems to be just smooth shaded. second is smooth with bottom flat third is smoothed with some supporting loops added?

Comment: @iKlsR Ah, that makes sense. I got the impression that it was somehow set up without additional geometry, but I'm not sure how that would work (does blender support importing custom normals?)

Comment: The third one was actually modified with scripting to set the vertex normals to the surface normal the currently selected face. This is intended to be used in a game so less geometry is better

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/70275/599

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, I think you should use a "subdivision surface" modifier, and smooth shading, to get what you want. Just add some edge on the cylinder top face and side surface, quite near the loop that divides them...

See below images:

[image]
[image]

or, for the cube version:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to enable **Object Data > Auto Smooth**, then set it to a value less than 90°.

[image: Enable Auto Smooth]

Seems to give the proper results when bevelled:

[image]