# Blender mesh gets strange normals in Unity 5

Tags: mesh, normals, unity

I'm having some trouble getting a mesh to look correctly when having smooth normals applied in Unity 5, the mesh itself is made in Blender and I suspect that its in there that I do something wrong.

My mesh originally was made up of several meshes that were later combined into one, with doubled vertices removed. In the example below each of the "lines" were separate as well as the sections between them. When I select "calculate normals" in Unity 5 and select a smoothing angle of 180 I get the result of the second image, what could be the cause of this?

I have other meshes that were combined in similar ways that do not show this error at all.

I would really appreciate some help here :)

[image: Mesh Lines]
[image: Mesh Smooth Normals (angle: 180)]

Comment: I don't know Unity at all but this clearly seems to be topology issue. Try to make smooth shaded mesh in Blender and then export to Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luke, I tried what you said and it did help quite a bit. thanks! :) But I'm still wondering why some meshes came out like this and others not, seems like I'm still missing something...

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70275/is-it-possible-to-get-automatic-smooth-edges-with-flat-faces-without-adding-geom This is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing back and forth I discovered that my problem was solved by combining the problematic meshes together with a correct one and then separating them again. How or why this worked I can't say, but it did the trick for me :)