# Funky Shading After Boolean

Tags: mesh, normals

So I just recently started with Blender 2.8. I'm working on a model and had a place where I needed to have a cylinder blend into a curved surface. I use booleans to merge the two meshes, and created a bevel where they intersected. However as you can see, I'm not getting some bizarre shading on the curved surface:

[image]

Here is the wireframe:

[image]

I do have a Weighted Normal modifier already applied. If I switch to flat shading, the artifacts disappear, however I need the surface to appear smooth. If at all possible I'm trying to avoid adding extra edges and geometry.

Autosmoothing is turned on, and an Edge Split modifier will not work for this application. It's occurring on a curved surface, so setting it to flat shading will also not work.

A sample of the problem area is here:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear, is your cylinder creating a hole in your shape? If not, you should give thickness to your pipe. Anyway, what do you call funky shading? If you're talking about the part that is just above the welding, it might be because of your stretched triangles. Maybe pack the hdri image and share your file?

Comment: Yes, the cylinder is creating a hole in the curved surface. The cylinder will eventually be capped, I just haven't gotten there yet. And yes, it's the spot just above the weld where it's not smooth. It happens below the weld, as well, though that's not visible, here.

Comment: So it could come from your geometry but maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sample of the problem area uploaded.

Comment: You're always going to have trouble with squeezing a 12-sided cylinder into a 4x4 grid.  Try with 8 or 16 sided cylinder and compare results, better yet, if it's low-poly, don't weld the geometry, just have it intersect.

Comment: Avoid booleans. Watch this link: **[The RIGHT way to cut holes in surfaces in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1jBOm_5NY)**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's both a topology and a *Weighted Normal* modifier problem:

- You should avoid tris if they are twisted and stretched, so you should correct your topology with quads.
- I don't know a lot about *Weighted Normal* modifier, [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140798/what-is-the-weighted-normal-modifier-for) is an explanation by Cgslav on how it works, it looks like it's mainly made for bevel, I'm not sure it's made to fake a smooth shape like yours, rather use *Subdivision Surface* if you can, or add a bit of geometry?

[image]

Comment: The problem with turning it into quads as is in your example is that it's going to change the arc of the surface as it approaches the weld.